# Agrupar fechas en base a diferencia de más de 30 dias entre dos consecutivas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Estimados, estoy desarrollando unas consultas y quiero tener una agrupación la cual entre fechas para cada `'pfr_Fault_Code'` no existan más de 30 días.

Si ejecutan el siguiente código, se puede ver una agrupación de `'pfr_Fault_Code'` por fecha y un conteo de eventos:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from time import time

df = pd.read_csv('FDE_before_delay_aviso_previo.csv', header=0, sep=',', usecols=[1,16,20,27,28],parse_dates = ['fault_date'])
df2=df.sort(columns=['CASS_ID','pfrs_pfr_date','fault_date'])
df2 = df2.reset_index(drop=True)

df2=df2.groupby(['pfr_Fault_Code','fault_date']).count()

print(df2)
```

Quiero contar lo mismo, pero **siempre y cuando no existan más de 30 días en cada fecha para cada `'pfr_Fault_Code'` desde la fecha más actual hacía atrás**. Por otro lado, las fechas están ordenadas. ¿En pandas será posible realizar directamente esto?

**Ejemplo:**

Para un `'pfr_Fault_Code'=XXXXXX` tengo las siguientes `'fault_date'=[2017/12/01],[2017/11/29],[2017/11/10],[2017/09/30],[2017/09/15]`

Desde la fecha más actual hacía atrás veo si existe un corte entre fechas superior a 30 días, el cual se genera entre `'[2017/11/10]` y `[2017/09/30]` por lo tanto me sirve `'fault_date'=[2017/12/01],[2017/11/29],[2017/11/10]`.

---

Estaba pensando añadir algo como esto, una nueva columna con la diferencia en días, pero no me funciona:

```
df2['diferencia'] =df2.groupby('pfr_Fault_Code')['fault_date'].transform(pd.Series.diff).fillna(df2['fault_date'])
```

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

---

El archivo CSV para poder ejecutar el código es el siguiente:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f8IFNvMA0Zbm_t0whweZjt4QSHR-ahVy/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Jorge para aclarar un poco, si tienes por ejemplo los siguientes valores de `fault_date` para un mismo `pfr_Fault_Code`: `[01/01/2017, 12/01/2017, 01/03/2017, 10/05/2017, 12/05/2017, 01/06/2017, 01/10/2017]`, ¿la salida debería ser 3?

Comment: @FJSevilla disculpa pero no estaba correcta la respuesta anterior, creo que es más simple que eso, viendo tu ejemplo solo debería quedar lo más próximo al día de hoy y cortar aquello que esté a más de 30 días, por ejemplo sólo me sirve `01/10/2017`. Siempre hay una fecha inicial o la más actual respecto no deben haber más de 30 días respecto a la anterior, y de anterior no más de 30 días respecto a la de más atrás, por eso en tu ejemplo sólo es válida `01/10/2017` y respecto a esa contar con groupby

Comment: @FJSevilla por eso pensaba en añadir una nueva columna que me indique la diferencia entre una fecha y la anterior, de esta forma podría saber cuando generar el corte si es que existiera uno mayor a 30 días. Añadiré un ejemplo arriba.

Comment: Es decir, que se deja de contar en el momento que hay un salto. Por ejemplo `[20/12/2017, 02/12/2017, 17/11/2017, 01/05/2017, 25/4/2017]` solo validaría las tres primeras, aunque luego entre `01/05/2017` y `25/4/2017` existan de nuevo menos de 30 días de diferencia. Es decir, en el momento que entre una fecha y la que le precede exista más de 30 días dejamos de contar sin importar el resto. ¿Es esto?

Comment: @FJSevilla exacto! el resto no importaría, como en el ejemplo que puse arriba.

Comment: @FJSevilla me parece muy ingeniosa y correcta tu respuesta, la estoy programando leyendo del archivo CSV pero la columna `groups` me tira solamente `False`. Lo otro, según mis datos el orden correcto es `df2=df.sort(columns=['CASS_ID','pfrs_pfr_date','fault_date'])`

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70681/discussion-between-fjsevilla-and-jorge-ponti).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar `pandas.DataFrame.groupby.diff()` junto a `count()` para crear una nueva columna que diferencie cada grupo de fechas dentro de un mismo valor de `pfr_Fault_Code` que no están separadas más de 30 días con respecto a la que le precede. Hecho esto, bastaría solo con quedarse con el primer grupo por cada valor de `pfr_Fault_Code`.

Veamos un ejemplo reproducible y simplificado:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'pfr_Fault_Code': ["111111", "111111", "111111", "111111", "111111", 
                           "222222", "222222", "222222", "222222", "222222",
                           "333333", "333333", "333333", "333333"], 
            'fault_date': ["2017/12/01", "2017/11/29","2017/11/10", "2017/09/30", "2017/09/15", 
                           "2017/10/01", "2017/05/29","2017/05/10", "2017/03/30", "2017/03/30", 
                           "2017/05/01", "2017/04/29","2017/04/10", "2017/01/30"]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['fault_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['fault_date'])

# Ordenamos de forma descendente las fechas, esto es un paso imprescindible
df.sort_values(by='fault_date', ascending = False, inplace = True)


df['groups'] = df.groupby('pfr_Fault_Code')['fault_date'].diff() < pd.Timedelta(days=-30)
df['groups'] = df.groupby('pfr_Fault_Code')["groups"].cumsum()
```

Con esto obtenemos el siguiente DataFrame:

```
   fault_date pfr_Fault_Code  groups
0  2017-12-01         111111     0.0
1  2017-11-29         111111     0.0
2  2017-11-10         111111     0.0
5  2017-10-01         222222     0.0
3  2017-09-30         111111     1.0
4  2017-09-15         111111     1.0
6  2017-05-29         222222     1.0
7  2017-05-10         222222     1.0
10 2017-05-01         333333     0.0
11 2017-04-29         333333     0.0
12 2017-04-10         333333     0.0
8  2017-03-30         222222     2.0
9  2017-03-30         222222     2.0
13 2017-01-30         333333     1.0
```

Ahora es muy simple obtener por cada valor de `pfr_Fault_Code` las filas hasta que una de las fechas de `fault_date` tiene una diferencia mayor de 30 días con respecto a la que le precede:

```
>>> df[df["groups"] == 0]

   fault_date pfr_Fault_Code  groups
0  2017-12-01         111111     0.0
1  2017-11-29         111111     0.0
2  2017-11-10         111111     0.0
5  2017-10-01         222222     0.0
10 2017-05-01         333333     0.0
11 2017-04-29         333333     0.0
12 2017-04-10         333333     0.0
```